# Find $a ,b$ vectors such that $H=\operatorname{Span}\{a , b \}$

Tags: linear-algebra

$$H= \operatorname{Span} \{ (1,1,1,1) , ( 1,3,1,3) , (-1,1,-1,1) , (3,1,3,1)\}$$
Can you help me to solve this kind of questions? 
I tried to do it myself, but I did not figured it out. I have a really long way to solve it. Maybe there is a bestway to solve it?

Comment: I see no question ? I only see $H$. What are $C,a$ and $b$ ?????

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  I assume that you are seeking two vectors which have the same span as the four you provide, but why would you make your readers guess what you are asking?  Also, if my reading is correct, how do you know this is a two dimensional space?  Have you, for instance, shown that it is not four dimensional?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

I assume that $C$ and $H$ should be the same. Then you have to pick two linearly independent vectors $a$ and $b$ out of the four vectors which span $H$.

Next, write the other two vectors as a linear combination of $a$ and $b$.

Finally, you can use that to write each element of $H$ as the linear combination of $a$ and $b$, hence $H=Span\{a,b\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that:
$$(−1,1,−1,1) = (1,3,1,3) - 2\cdot (1,1,1,1)$$
$$(3,1,3,1) = 4\cdot (1,1,1,1) - (1,3,1,3)$$

so $$H = \operatorname{span}\{(1,1,1,1), (1,3,1,3), (-1,1,-1,1), (3,1,3,1)\} = \operatorname{span}\{(1,1,1,1), (1,3,1,3)\}$$

Furthermore, $\{(1,1,1,1), (1,3,1,3)\}$ is linearly independent so it is a basis for $H$.